# Barba - will preloading my assets for the next page speed up its load time?

Tags: javascript, caching, barbajs

I looked around and I don't **think** this is a duplicate, but forgive me if it is. I'm working on a sort of "showcase" for my agency that consists of five pages. I'm using barba.js to transition the pages, and the user will always go through the pages in the same sequence. It's pretty image and video heavy, so I'd like to use the time that the user is browsing one section to preload and cache assets for the next section. I know how to do this using js, but my question is - **will loading page 2's assets on page 1 actually speed up load time on page 2?** I have a pretty poor understanding of how browser caching works, and I don't want to eat up memory on page 1 if it won't pay off on loading page 2.

Comment: Generally, don't worry about client memory here in 2022, unless you're serving up massive 3D models or something. Caching is based on URL, so if you use the same URL all the time for scripts or images you use, then they'll be cached.

Comment: @Pointy perfect, thank you for the quick answer.